# I added a Content-Security-Policy but still the security warning appears

Tags: electron, content-security-policy

I added a Content-Security-Policy as suggested here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#6-define-a-content-security-policy and here: https://content-security-policy.com/examples/electron/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>New Electron App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Our new Electron app</span>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But still I get this message:
“Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy). This renderer process has either no Content Security Policy set or a policy with “unsafe-eval” enabled. This exposes users of this app to unnecessary security risks. This warning will not show up once the app is packaged.”

[image]

How to solve this security warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Least two ways to disable CSP : no package.json

---

#### Disable through CLI

Consider running Electron's app source file main.js within CLI as so: `ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS=true npx electron main.js`

> Hereby using **npx** I did consider you was clever and installed Electron locally beforehand .

#### Disable through the process

Define anywhere (*top-level would be at best*) the following  `process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS']=true`

- [info taken from](https://dev.to/projektorius96/content-security-policy-csp-warning-in-electron-how-to-disable-it-abe)

Comment: Thank you. It seems working fine

Comment: Glad it helped <3

Answer (score 7):

This is intended behaviour, as it says it will trigger on unset **or** set policy allowing unsafe-evals. They simply want you to make sure to not add any evals without being 100% sure.

[For why this is only displayed when building](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#electron-security-warnings) it's only the case if you build your application and your binary is still called "electron".

[image: section from electron docs]

Comment: That's true, it's just warning to notice us about existing policy of CSP , not a stop sign from continue developing further . I assume this is least applicable for 100% offline apps

Answer (score 5):

Add `script-src 'self'` to the CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';">
```

It should fix the issue. It's a feature of Electron security parser - it does not know abt fallback so thinks that script-src is absent, nitty-gritty is [here](http://csplite.com/csp203/#warn_with_CSP)

Comment: I added this but still get the error. I am using Quasar framework and Electron

Comment: It could possible if your app uses a `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';` HTTP header, and you add a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';">` in try to fix error. An HTTP header is still unsafe, Electron security system checks both header and meta tag.

Comment: I am able to suppress the message by using the answer below from @hans-koch. I added `process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true'` in my app and the messages are gone.

Comment: Yes, but in this case you'll lose other security warnings which can occur after improving/modifying your app. You do not need to supress securuty warnings, they appear in [Dev mode only](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#electron-security-warnings) and do not appear in production.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add this environment variable to your `package.json`.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS=true electron ."
  }
}
```

Comment: I added it to the package.json but still get this warning message

Comment: Are you running `npm run electron`?

Comment: I also still get the error when adding this to package.json. I am using Quasar framework and Electron.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of days searching for the solution I found at VScode sources a function when app is ready

```js
w.protocol.registerHttpProtocol(I.Schemas.vscodeRemoteResource, (Pe, Le) => {
    Le({ url: Pe.url.replace(/^vscode-remote-resource:/, 'http:'), method: Pe.method })
})
```

So you need a Protocol to replace to `http` and you have to register as privileged for example

```js
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{ scheme: 'server', privileges: { bypassCSP: true } }])
/*----*/
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    protocol.registerHttpProtocol('server', (request, response: any) => {
        const redirect: any = {
            method: request.method,
            url: request.url.replace(/^remote:/, 'http:')
        }

        if (request.method === 'POST' || request.method === 'PUT') {
            redirect.uploadData = {
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: request.uploadData ? request.uploadData[0].bytes.toString() : ''
            }
        }

        response(redirect)
    })
})
```

And then, when you make a resquest `server://localhost:3000/api` you don't will get the error CSP - Content-Security-Policy